# JPA - An entity's property type depends on a column value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with a 3rd party database with the following table:

```
Node
----
id (int not null)
fKey (varchar(max) null)
refTable (varchar(max) null)
```

`fkey` is the value of the primary key of `refTable`. `refTable` contains one the following values `Car`, `Truck`, or `Boat`. My node entity currently looks like:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Node {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "fKey")
  private String foreignKey;

  @Column(name = "refTable")
  private String targetTable;
}
```

But I'd prefer the node entity refer to a `Car` entity when targetTable is `Car`. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Node {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "carId")
  private Car car;
  
  // ok with having truck and boat 
  // here too and being null when refTable refers to Car

}
```

How can I set up this mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better aproach would be to use inheritance. You should turn your Node class the MainClass and inherit from it to Car, Truck and Boat

```
@Entity
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = “refTable”)
public class Node {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  
  
}
```

Your subclassed implementation should look like

```
@Entity
@Data
@DiscriminatorValue(“Car”)
public class CarNode extends Node {
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fKey")
  private Car car;
  
}
```

The same for Truck and Boat. Your query for Nodes would return you CarNodes, TruckNodes or BoatNodes